# Нужна помощь с алгоритмом вычисления суммы на C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, числовые-последовательности

Пишу алгоритм для вычисления результата суммы по формуле, для разного количества аргументов. Алгоритм для возрастающей суммы работает у меня хорошо, но я не понимаю как адаптировать этот алгоритм под убывающую сумму. Ничего в голову не приходит.

Метод принимает 4 аргумента: стартовый аргумент, конечный аргумент, количество элементов последовательности и шаг.

[image: Формула]

Вот по такой формуле рассчитывается сумма. Сумма рассчитывается для всех аргументов находящихся в промежутке между стартовым и конечным. Каждый последующий аргумент рассчитывается по формуле - предыдущий аргумент + шаг.
Значение k так же увеличивается на значение шага при каждой итерации вычисления суммы.

Объект Container2 выступает как контейнер для полученных значений.

```
private static List<Container2> func1(double endArg, int step, int n, double startArg)
    {
        if (startArg < endArg)
        {
            List<Container2> result = new List<Container2>();

            double res = 0;
            double x = startArg;
            int k = 0;

            do
            {
                if ((x - step) == endArg)
                    break;
                else 
                    if (x > endArg)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка во входных данных");
                        return null;
                    }

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    res += (Math.Cos((k * Math.PI) / 4) / factr(k)) * Math.Pow(x, k);
                    k += step;
                }

                result.Add(new Container2(res, x));

                x += step;

            } while (true);

            return result;
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: `step = ABS(step) * SIGN(endArg-startArg)`... Или `If (endArg<startArg) {SWAP(endArg,startArg)}`

Comment: Что значит sign? Второй вариант не подходит, ибо тогда проверка корректности введенных данных не будет работать

Comment: `Sign()` - это функция, возвращающая -1 для отрицательных аргументов, +1 для положительных, и 0 для нуля. Ну или мож метод какой или свойство... Math.Sign там или ещё откуда.

Comment: Что такое убывающая, я не вижу, в чем проблема.

Comment: startArg < endArg это корректность? Тогда как задать убывающую?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka да, корректность, не знаю, поэтому сюда и обратился

Comment: Что такое убывающая сумма? Математически

Comment: Сумма убывающего ряда*

Comment: Что то не так с заданием. При k == 0 будет деление на 0.

Comment: Еще не понятно, почему один и тот же шаг изменяет и Х и К. Это точно то, что вы хотите?

Comment: @iRumba, Не будет потому что 0! = 1

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, не знал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал по быстрому вот такой код. Чтобы не было путаницы разбил все что можно по отдельным функциям. Выдает результаты хоть в случае когда старт меньше конца, хоть в обратном (при этом в обратном случае значения будут вычисляться на убывание, хотя для вычисления суммы это и не имеет значения)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        foreach (var sum in GetSums(5, 10, 5.5, 1))
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    // Здесь вычисляем все суммы для k от 1 до n
    static IEnumerable<double> GetSums(int n, double start, double end, int step)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            yield return CalculateSum(i, start, end, step);
    }

    // Здесь вычисляем сумму для конкретного k
    static double CalculateSum(int k, double start, double end, int step)
    {
        return GetRange(start, end, step).Select(v => Calculate(k, v)).Sum();
    }

    // Здесь вычисляем значение по формуле (без суммы)
    static double Calculate(int k, double x)
    {
        return Math.Cos(k * Math.PI / 4) / Factorial(k) * Math.Pow(x, k);
    }

    // Факториал
    static int Factorial(int k)
    {
        var res = 1;
        for(var i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
    }

    // Здесь получаем перечисление элементов от первого значения до второго с заданым шагом. Если первый элемент больше второго,
    // то перечисление будет убывающим
    static IEnumerable<double> GetRange(double val1, double val2, int step)
    {
        if (val1 < val2)
            step = Math.Abs(step);
        else
            step = -Math.Abs(step);
        for (var i = val1; Math.Abs((val2 - i)) > Math.Abs(step); i += step)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

Немного поправил код. Теперь факториал 0 равен 1. :)